# URL Redirect Rule - Regex - How To Capture Part Of URL

Tags: regex, redirect

I am trying to write a redirect rule that will redirect the user only if the match the locales: en-us, zh-tw, fr-be. If they do not match these locales, the rule will ignore them. The user will be redirected to another site with just their country code.

`foo.com/en-us/bar => foo2.com/us/bar2
foo.com/zh-tw/bar => foo2.com/tw/bar2
foo.com/fr-be/bar => foo2.com/be/bar2`

This is my attempt, but I'm not sure how to extract the last two characters from $1:

`^/?foo.com/([en-us|zh-tw|fr-be])/bar$ => http://foo2.com/$1/bar2
^/?foo.com/[en-(us)|zh-(tw)|fr-(be)]/bar$ => http://foo2.com/$1/bar2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:
`^/?foo.com/(en)-(us)|(zh)-(tw)|(fr)-(be)(/bar)$`
`$0 --> foo2.com/$2$4$6$7`

Tested in PHP.  Working for all test cases and excludes other combinations.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the safe effect without having to use so many variables?

Comment: @Jon, no.  Why do you have a problem with so many placeholders?

Comment: In my example I only have 3 locales. In my actual code, I have 20+ locales (and this list will only grow).

Comment: @Jon, I'm still not seeing a problem.  If regex can't solve your problem then string parsing will be the next alternative.

Answer (score -1):

If you know you're going to have the format of a two character language followed by a two character country you could try:

given "foo.com/fr-be/bar"

^/?foo.com/(\w{2})-(\w{2})/bar$

$1 == fr
$2 == be

Comment: How would I restrict the capture to certain locales?